# What triggers class leveling in Dungeon Raid?

Tags: ios, dungeon-raid

This question refers to the recent Dungeon Raid update with character classes.

I know that "class levels" only come from killing special monsters. But is there a formula for how many special monsters you have to kill to get a trophy? My subjective (i.e. probably wrong) impression is that using Big Game Hunter doesn't help get trophies any faster (though of course it's great for "character levels", especially in conjunction with Masochism).

Comment: Unfortunately, I've never seen a Dungeon Raid user guide or walk-through out in the wild. I wish there was one built into the game. If you check out [the game's website](http://dungeonraid.atspace.com/), there's a support address you can send your question to. If you here back, please post the answer! The more information we can get about this game, the better. It is the only game I've bought that I still play, especially with the new 1.3 update.

Comment: I can't back this up, but it seems like you only unlock classes playing the initial class (human adventurer). I think that when you play a class, your XP goes towards levelling up that class vs unlocking new ones.

Comment: It can't be based solely on number of boss kills. I have a round running currently that I can keep going perpetually as I've been able to set things up so I can level/upgrade much faster than the monsters get tougher. I must have killed in excess of 300 bosses at this point and haven't received any upgrades or class levels.

Comment: My theory into the way it works is when you see a special monster, you don't kill it. You let it sit there pounding on you. It's like a test and after a while it'll disappear and turn into a trophy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Playing Normal mode, I've unlocked characters and levelled up classes fast(ish) using Big Game Hunter. You do need to kill *a lot* of special characters to level up classes, but in 8 games on the iphone, I have all classes unlocked, and the Mage levelled up to level 10.

I'd be intrigued to know what constitutes a high character level in a game on Normal mode? I tend to feel that hitting about 1000 turns, and character level of something over 200 is a good go - given that by that point all the items tend to be named things like 'legendary blah' and 'godly blah'.

In my experience the best combination of skills to get to this point is Heal, Repair, Dazzle and Big Game Hunter, with the Mage class. Shapeshifter's special ability plus Big Game Hunter means that you can kill a lot of special monsters fast.

Answer (score 4):

I think the developer posted the rules on the thread in the toucharcade forum somewhere:

1) You can't do it on easy

2) You get a trophy for every 15 or so specials/bosses you kill. I forget the exact number but it was around there.

3) The most you can unlock in one game is (3) and I've noticed it takes more special/boss kills to unlock the 2nd and 3rd in the same game

4) If you reach the maximum you can get in one game (and keep going) quite often the first one you kill the next game will get you one. So it seems you can still build towards the 10-15 special trigger... it just won't trigger after the third trophy until you start a new game.

5) Each trophy has a 50% chance to unlock a new class or 50% to level up the class you are playing. So if you're playing the adventurer (or a maxed out class) then every trophy unlocks a class. Likewise if you've unlocked all the classes every trophy levels up your class.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently on "easy" you don't unlock anything. Or so my brother says.

Comment: It certainly seems to be quicker to unlock things in the harder difficulty levels, even though I regularly get a higher score in Easy.

Answer (score 1):

After a certain number of special monsters killed, a trophy drops and this either levels up your current class or unlocks another one. Big Game Hunter does work to speed up this process

Comment: Really? I killed 50-60 specials in a BGH round and then in a shorter round later w/o BGH I unlocked 2 classes.

Answer (score 0):

I have unlocked the priest while playing the barbarian. So it can be done. Had to kill a lot of specials though.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a probability of getting it determined by an RNG, which would explain why some people got "lucky" and some haven't. It probably has to do with playstyle, not the specific number of how many you killed.

Comment: "probably a probability"? It's preferred when answers have facts to back them up, not supposition.